# cannot login to database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

Cannot open database "Architect" requested by the login. The login failed.

> Login failed for user 'Local System
>   Name\ASPNET'.

```
 <add name="ArchitectConnectionString" 
      connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.15,1433;
                        Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Architect;
                        Integrated Security=True" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
```

How can I solve this error

Comment: Please show us your connection string.

Answer (score 2):

Your website/web app is most likely running on WinXP. On that platform the ASP.Net worker process runs as the ASPNET user. If in your database connection string you have specified *Integrated Security*, then that is the user it will try to login to your database as.

So, either change your database connection string to use a specific username and password (i.e. use SQL Authentication), or set up a login on the server instance for the ASPNET user, and map it to a user on the Architect database.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SQL Server Management Studio to check that the ASPNET user has a SQL Server login that allows access to the Architect database.